# Sqlite frequent Header access

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite in my application only for read access. The DB gets hit often by my application and I could see that the header(100 bytes) of the database is read every time when i access the database.
Precisely speaking, 16 bytes from the 24th byte of the header is read everytime. My question is , if the database is used only for read purpose, why the header is read everytime as the database connection is not closed?..can we make it read it only once?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just curious, how do you see that header is read every time?

Answer (score 0):

Google search gave me this link, and it says

"Your process may promise that it will only read the database, but there
might be some other process writing to it.
Not being a server, sqlite has no other way to find that out than by
reading the header over and over again. It has to check whether the
schema was changed, or whatever other info is in those bytes."

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg69900.html